# How to replace white characters from string in jmeter

Tags: string, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

def path = vars.get("BaseFilePath") + "/" + vars.get("FhirVersion") + "/Get/Patient/";
def newLine = System.getProperty('line.separator')
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

//address
def addressCSV = new File(path + 'address.csv')
def addressCityCSV = new File(path + 'address-city.csv')
def addressCountryCSV = new File(path + 'address-country.csv')
def addressPostalCode = new File(path + 'address-postalcode.csv')
def addressState = new File(path + 'address-state.csv')

def replacement = {    
    if (it == ' ') {
        '%20'
    } else if (it == '/') {
        '%2F'    
    } else if (it == '|')
    {
        '%7C'
    }   
    else {
        null
    }
}

def address = JsonPath.read(response, '$..address')
address.each { eachAddress ->
    eachAddress.each { subAddress ->
        subAddress.get('line').each { line ->
            addressCSV << line << newLine
        }

        addressCityCSV << subAddress.get('city').collectReplacements(replacement) << newLine
        addressState << subAddress.get('state').collectReplacements(replacement) << newLine
        addressPostalCode << subAddress.get('postalCode').collectReplacements(replacement) << newLine
        addressCountryCSV << subAddress.get('country').collectReplacements(replacement) << newLine

    }
}
```

This is a JSR223 code in jmeter for extracting values from json string
code is working till fetching values from json

values of subAddress.get('city') = hawkin city and 
subAddress.get('postalCode') = http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn|C999-87-3780

so i wanted to replace the white character, :, /, | with %20, %2F, %7C
and if the string doesnot contain any of these then writing the string to csv file

The code is not working

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something strange, my expectation is that you should be looking for some form of [URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), for instance JavaScript [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) perform the replacement according to your requirements.

You can call it using JMeter's [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) like:

```
${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent("String you would like to encode"),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Javasccript]

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: Can i use the __JavaScript().function inside JSR223 PostProcessor, if i can how to do that

Comment: Actually my suggestion was to encode the variables directly where required, i.e. in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body. If you want to use it inside JSR223 PostProcessor I would recommend going for something like `def encoded = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn").eval('encodeURIComponent("String you would like to encode")')
`. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: yes sir i will go for the first approach, thank you for the solution